# Counting letters and numbers in string

Tags: javascript

I write a code that works with letter but not with numbers
I know it maybe a little complicated but this is how I could do it;
with numbers it produce ordered Array and I don't know why

```js
var orderedCount = function(text) {
  let splitted = text.split('');
  let countedLetters = splitted.reduce((AllLetters, letter) => {
    (letter in AllLetters) ? AllLetters[letter]++: AllLetters[letter] = 1;
    return AllLetters
  }, {})
  let result = Object.keys(countedLetters).map((key) => {
    return [(key), countedLetters[key]]
  })
  return result;

};
console.log(orderedCount("abracadabra")); //[['a',5], ['b',2], ['r',2], ['c',1], ['d',1]]
console.log(orderedCount("212")); //[['1',1], ['2',2]]
```

```
[['1',1],['2',2]]
```

should be

```
[['2',2],['1',1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the array directly using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method where use a reference object which keeps object reference based on `letter` value.

```js
var orderedCount = function(text) {
  const ref = {};
  return text.split('').reduce((arr, letter) => {
    (letter in ref) ? ref[letter][1]++: arr.push(ref[letter] = [letter, 1]);
    return arr;
  }, []);
};
console.log(orderedCount("abracadabra")); //[['a',5], ['b',2], ['r',2], ['c',1], ['d',1]]
console.log(orderedCount("212")); //[['1',1], ['2',2]]
```

Refer : [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Since es2015 onwards non-integer keys are kept inserting order and integer keys are sorted numerically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array and use `sort` to sort the element 1

```js
var orderedCount = function(text) {
  let splitted = text.split('');
  let countedLetters = splitted.reduce((AllLetters, letter) => {
    (letter in AllLetters) ? AllLetters[letter]++: AllLetters[letter] = 1;
    return AllLetters
  }, {})

  let result = Object.entries(countedLetters).sort((a, b) => {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  })

  return result
};
console.log(orderedCount("abracadabra")); 
console.log(orderedCount("212"));
```

---

Shorter Version:

```js
var orderedCount = function(text) {
  return Object.entries(text.split('').reduce((c, v) => {
    c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + 1;
    return c;
  }, {})).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

};
console.log(orderedCount("abracadabra")); 
console.log(orderedCount("212"));
```

Comment: it return the result sorted descending instead of ascending . I want the result to be at the original order

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort you `result` by count, because by default numeric keys in `Object` will be in [**ascending order**](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/#1-integer-indices)

```js
var orderedCount = function(text) {
  let splitted = text.split('');
  let countedLetters = splitted.reduce((AllLetters, letter) => {
    (letter in AllLetters) ? AllLetters[letter]++: AllLetters[letter] = 1;
    return AllLetters
  }, {})
  let result = Object.keys(countedLetters).map((key) => {
    return [(key), countedLetters[key]]
  })
  return result.sort((a,b)=>b[1] - a[1]);

};
console.log(orderedCount("abracadabra")); //[['a',5], ['b',2], ['r',2], ['c',1], ['d',1]]
console.log(orderedCount("212")); //[['1',1], ['2',2]]
```